# How to structure module with interactive methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object

I'm working on a program which parses data and presents it to users for annotation for the purpose of generating training data for an ML model. I'm looking for advice on how to structure this module's classes in the most logical way. I'm a bit new to OOP; abstracting beyond the typical "vehicle->car->car_brand" model of class inheritance is sort of where I find myself. The basic flow of this program is:

1. Retrieve messy data from external source
2. Parse data to create local representation which only contains information relevant to this task
3. Present data to users, who then mark it up with annotations
4. Generate statistics on those annotations

Should the interactive methods be part of the same class as the cleaned-up data? What about the methods to generate statistics?

I've tried subsuming all functionalities of this program under one class definition, which works fine but seems reductive and probably difficult for others to grasp quickly. Here is how I think the program might be structured (apologies for all the pseudo-code):

```py
class AnnotationData:
    # has methods to retrieve messy data and smooth it into what humans need to see to do this task. Populates class attributes to represent that data.
class AnnotationMethods(AnnotationData):
    # has methods to interact with data
class AnnotationStatistics(AnnotationData): 
    # has methods to generate statistics on data which has been augmented by humans

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create base class
    # populate base class with messy data
    # smooth messy data into human-readable format
    # Instantiate AnnotationMethods class
    # Human does annotation
    # Instantiate AnnotationStatistics class
    # Return sweet sweet stats
```

Subsuming all of this into a single class works fine. I'm just wondering what the best practice is for divvying up methods which humans interact with from methods which just populate data.

Answer (score -1):

Check this library https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe. They have a similar workflow as yours.